# how can i use functions that needs a ui thread without giving it context in android?

Tags: android, multithreading

I'm using a service class in my app which runs for long time period and i sometimes need a ui thread to do my work such as finding a contact name which make me create a cursor variable, that cursor variable needs a content resolver which needs a context.

how i can do this work freely without any ui thread?

Comment: `Service` is a subclass of `Context`, you can simply call `getContentResolver()` in it.

Comment: sorry, i will change my question.

Comment: Thanks, the problem was that i use the function in a runnable class,i've passed a content resolver variable from the service to it and it works.@earthw0rmjim

Comment: If the `Runnable` is in your `Service` class, you can just reference the `Service` as `YourServiceName.this`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to get the UI thread from another thread (obviously), but you'll be able to get a Context, which is certainly what you need.

And a `Service` is a `Context`, so you have access to any method like getResource() or getContentResolver() with a Service reference.

Comment: You can in fact get the UI thread from another thread: https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html

Comment: Well no, actually, you really can't, BUT if you are already in the UI Thread you can keep a reference to it by creating a `Handler` instance, which will allow you to later call some piece of code in the UI Thread. But in the case of Service, you won't be able to create this instance, so....

Comment: @Orabîg All you have to do is instantiate a `Handler` that uses the `Looper` of the main thread. Why would it not be possible from a `Service` (or any background thread)? It's really simple actually.

Comment: Well, you're right. I was wrong thinking that a Service has no UI, and thus no way to access the UI Thread. Sorry about the mistakes.